# Creating directory after each event

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I am trying to create a directory after each button click event. 
This works just until 10 directories

> ```
> 5612cfea107f9e0f356b3dee_1
> 5612cfea107f9e0f356b3dee_2
> 5612cfea107f9e0f356b3dee_3
> 5612cfea107f9e0f356b3dee_n
> ```

and then I am getting this error:

> ```
> Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'user/public/uploadGallery/5612cfea107f9e0f356b3dee_10'
> ```

```
app.post('/createDirectories', function(req, res) {

    var id = '5612cfea107f9e0f356b3dee';

  var pathDirectory = __dirname + '/public/uploadGallery/' + id;

        fs.readdir(__dirname + '/public/uploadGallery/', function (err, files) { 

        var countVal = files.filter(junk.not).length;
        var fileVal = files.filter(junk.not);
                    if(countVal == '0'){ 

                        fs.mkdirSync(pathDirectory + '_' + 1);  
                        console.log("Directory created: " + pathDirectory + '_' + 1);           
                    }else{

                        var lastElem = fileVal[fileVal.length-1];
                        var lastElemSplitValue = lastElem.split("_")[1];
                        var valInt = parseInt(lastElemSplitValue, 10) +1;
                        fs.mkdirSync(pathDirectory + '_' + valInt);
        }
        });
});
```

What can I do to fix this problem? I wanna create n directories.

Thanks for your help. 
machu

Comment: ok, now it should be correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is sorting

you'll have directories

- _1
- _2
- ...
- _9

add the 10th - and, in **alphabetical** or **lexical** order, you'll have

- _1
- _10
- _2
- ...
- _9

so, the last folder is `_9` ... 9 + 1 = 10 ... that already exists!

You could change your code to

```
    } else {
        var valInt = Math.max.apply(null, fileVal.map(function(entry) {
            return parseInt(entry.split("_").pop(), 10);
        })) + 1;
        fs.mkdirSync(pathDirectory + '_' + valInt);
    }
```

This applies Math.max to the result of mapping the fileVal entries to the parseInt of the last part of each of the fileVal entries split by '_'

Comment: Ahhh okey, then I should sort it! I will try this.

Comment: if you sort it, you'll have `_1`, `_10`, `_2`, ... `_9` ... so ... no, sorting is the source of the problem - sort it by create time will work 99% of the time, unsorted should work 99% of the time too ... best thing to do is to loop through and find the highest value

Comment: Ok! Any suggestion how could do this. "files" is an array.

Comment: I've added a suggestion